# How to prevent mysql errors from showing tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

On my production serve when some error with mysql shows up, laravel framework returns the full error message which shows the query, is there some command to remove the query from mysql error message ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should disable debug mode in your `config/app.php` file to hide sensitive information of errors.

As Laravel document: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors

> The `debug` option in your `config/app.php` configuration file
>   determines how much information about an error is actually displayed
>   to the user. By default, this option is set to respect the value of
>   the `APP_DEBUG` environment variable, which is stored in your .env
>   file.
>
> For local development, you should set the `APP_DEBUG` environment
>   variable to `true`. In your production environment, this value should
>   always be `false`. If the value is set to `true` in production, you
>   risk exposing sensitive configuration values to your application's end
>   users.

Comment: it's already on false, but mysql errors keeps appearing